# Tkinter resize frame inside canvas does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to resize a frame inside my canvas, so that the frame covers the whole window.
I did some googleing and saw some people are using a resize function, but this doesn't work for me.
I get the following error message:

> _tkinter.TclError: invalid boolean operator in tag search expression

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('400x400')
        self.root.title("A simple GUI")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, background='GREEN',width=900,height=300,scrollregion=(0,0,500,2000))
        self.scrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(self.canvas,orient="vertical",command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        self.main = tk.Frame(self.canvas,bg='BLUE')
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.main, anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>",  self.resize_frame)
        for _ in range(30):
            MyCoolFrame(self.main)
    
    def resize_frame(self, e):
        canvas_width = e.width
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.main, width = canvas_width)
class MyCoolFrame:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master,bg='RED')
        for i in range(5):
            tk.Label(self.frame,text=f'Cool Label {i}').pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=2,pady=10)
        self.frame.pack(side=tk.TOP,pady=10)

a = MainGUI()
a.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `.itemconfig()` requires the result of `self.canvas.create_window()` as the item identifier, rather than the Frame itself.

Comment: omg thanks, what a silly mistake :D, guess this happens when I just copy code without trying to understand it